# is $L^2[0,1]$ orthogonal to $L^2[1,2]$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Is it true or false that every element $f \in L^2[0,1]$ is orthogonal to every element $g \in L^2[1,2]$, where both spaces are treated as subspaces of $L^2[0,2]$? (*Edit: I treat these as subspaces by associating each $f\in L^2[0,1]$ with an element $f_2 \in L^2[0,2]$ defined as $f_2(t) = f(t)$ if $t \in [0,1]$ and $f_2(t)=0$ if $t\in (1,2]$*)

I thought this might be true because $\langle f, g\rangle$ is computed with a Lebesgue integral, which I thought should not depend on a (bounded) function's value at any *specific* point in the range of integration. Since the intervals $[0, 1]$ and $[1, 2]$ intersect just at $\{1\}$, then region of integration for which both functions are nonzero is at most a point, which vaguely feels like it should result in $\langle f, g\rangle = 0$, but this is clearly not a rigorous argument.

However if we think of $L^2[0,1]$ as a closed subspace of $L^2[0,2]$, then the algebraic complement of $L^2[0,1]$ should be open and so cannot be $L^2[1,2]$.

Comment: What do you mean by algebraic complement and why should it be open?

Comment: How can you treat one space as a subspace of $L^2[0,2]$ when the elements of the other spaces are only defined on a specific subinterval?

Comment: @TedShifrin by the complement I just meant the space $Z$ s.t. $L^2[0,1] \oplus Z = L^2[0,2]$ (with respect to the embedding inferred by the answer below). Intuitively I expected $Z=L^2(1,2]$ would be open/not complete but now I see that was a silly thing to expect...

Comment: @whpowell96 Yeah, how does he dare to use the obvious, commonly used convention without pointing it out explicitly? That is quite an intelligent question to come up with in the first place :)

Comment: @Yaddle I don't think that this convention is commonly used without *very explictly* defining how to extend functions from one interval to anthoer. My comment was not meant to be deriding at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted by @whpowell96, your statement of the problem misses the specific way in which you embed $L^{2}[0, 1]$ and $L^{2}[1, 2]$ into $L^{2}[0, 2]$. If you define the embedding of the function from $L^{2}[0, 1]$ into $L^{2}[0, 2]$ to equal zero at $[1, 2]$, and the embedding of the function from $L^{2}[1, 2]$ to equal zero at $L^{2}[0, 1]$, as your post seems to suggest, then it is, of course, true that
$$\int_{0}^{2}\overline{f(x)}g(x)dx=0$$
for $f(x)$ from $L^2[0, 1]$ and $g(x)$ from $L^{2}[1, 2]$. Note that this is usually not the way the notion of $L^{2}[a, b]$ functions is treated. For instance, it is common for a family of polynomials to form an orthonormal system at $L^{2}[a,b]$, yet polynomials are zero only at a finite number of points. The fact that they belong to $L^{2}[a, b]$ only means they are square-integrable on $[a,b]$, and tells nothing of their behaviour on a different segment of the line. So two functions, one from $L^2[0, 1]$ and another from $L^{2}[1, 2]$, can easily be non-orthogonal on $[0, 2]$, moreover, a function from $L^2[0, 1]$ can easily be undefined on $[1, 2]$ or not belong to $L^{2}[0, 2]$.

Comment: Thanks, and yes that was the embedding I had in mind. So is it correct to say that $L^2[0,2] = L^2[0,1] \oplus L^2[1,2]$ in this case?

Comment: As I said, that's not how people use the notation $L^{2}[a,b]$. $L^{2}[a,b]$ is the space of all functions that are square-integrable on $[a, b]$. If you denote as the space $V^{2}[0,1]$ the space of square-integrable functions on $[0, 1]$ with support inside $[0, 1]$, then $V^{2}[0, 2]$, is, I guess, $V^{2}[0, 1]\oplus V^{2}[1, 2]$, but $L^{2}[0, 1]$ is much, much bigger than $V^{2}[0, 1]$, and $L^{2} [0, 2]$ is __smaller__ than both $L^{2}[0, 1]$ and $L^{2}[1, 2]$ (it is a subspace of both), since every function from $L^{2}[0, 2]$ belongs to $L^{2}[0, 1]$, but not vice versa.

Comment: So no, $L^{2}[0, 2]$ is __not__ $L^{2}[0, 1]\oplus L^{2}[1, 2]$, at least if you want other people to understand you. $L^{2}[0, 2]$ is a __subspace__ of both $L^{2}[0, 1]$ and $L^{2}[1, 2]$.

Comment: It is perhaps easier to understand if you introduce prologation and restrication operators tha expand/restrict the domains of functions to different domains. As defined, the spaces in question are not related to each other at all without a way to define them on other domains.